# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, typeerror

Everything works fine but from time to time there is a problem with the function. This makes it impossible to click a button and select a value from list. I tried to debug it but nothing is returned in the console.

```
_getSimpleProductId: function (element) {
        var allOptions = element.config.options,
            value = element.value,
            config;

        config = _.filter(allOptions, function (option) {
            return option.id === value;
        });
        config = _.first(config);

        return _.isEmpty(config) ?
            undefined :
            _.first(config.allowedProducts);

    }
```

Error occurs:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined

I think I have to change my question to "What I'm doing wrong?".

Comment: `element.config` is `undefined`. What value are you expecting it to have?

Answer (score 0):

you should null check element.config

```
var allOptions = element.config ? element.config.options : null;
```

It looks like it's not always defined in your code

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `element.config` is `undefined`.
You can either go with Basem's anwser (which would totally work) or find the source of the problem.

To me it looks like you expect to have `options` for the rest of your code, so I would go with the second solution.

Cheers!